# How do I get an integer out of NSNumber

Tags: iphone, ios5, int, nsnumber

I have this code, I save total second counting and load it in result view controller. and in my result view controller, I put this code,

```
- (void) counting
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSNumber *loadSecond = [defaults objectForKey:@"saveSecond"];
    NSLog(@"last save is %@", loadSecond); // in here, log is displaying 30 seconds
    scratch = fmod(secondCount,3600);
    hour =  secondCount / 3600;
    minute = scratch / 60;
    second = fmod(scratch,60);
    labelRecord.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d:%d", hour , minute, second];
}
```

From above, NSLog is displaying my last save counting for 30 seconds, and it is right but how do i change that 30 seconds to secondCount? because i want use it in my labelRecord.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line

```
NSNumber *loadSecond = [defaults objectForKey:@"saveSecond"];
```

to

```
int loadSecond = [[defaults objectForKey:@"saveSecond"] intValue];
```

This assumes that the object for the key saveSecond is a `NSNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

use the intValue message

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/intValue

Answer (score 1):

A quick look in [the docuemntation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) would show that there's an `NSUserDefaults` method that returns an integer:

```
NSInteger loadSecond = [defaults integerForKey:@"saveSecond"];
```

`NSInteger` is just an `int`. There's also `NSUInteger` which is unsigned.